# Py2Exe Sudden Error with a favicon.ico from a working script

Tags: tkinter, exe, py2exe

I just met a sudden error using py2exe I have a script Fully working that I can't get working through py2exe.
The problem is that I have already complete the nearly same code and not touched the part that is not working anymore.

My error code is

```
File "SAWB.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 2080, in wm_iconbitmap
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "\favicon.ico" not defined
[13900] Failed to execute script SAWB
```

And my code start like this (This is the part where py2exe seems to not work)

```
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
CurrentPath=os.path.dirname(__file__)

def KillM():
    MainWindow.destroy()
def KillS():
    SuccessWindow.destroy()

MainWindow = Tk()
MainWindow.title("name")
MainWindow.geometry('376x69')
MainWindow.iconbitmap(CurrentPath+"\\favicon.ico") #7
Label(MainWindow, text='name.wordpress.com')
filename = fd.askdirectory(title="Name")
filename = filename + "/yes.txt"
```

As I said my code is working when using just python but not working once compiled, and I previously compiled the nearly same code(with literally the same code part as shared, I only modified stuffs that do not disturb my code.) and this code works and have this icon.
I compiled using
`pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon=123.ico TheCode.py`
Also tried just `pyinstaller.exe TheCode.py` , and this is how I founded the error
I tried to re install it but nothing changed and my code and ico aren't corrupted.

If you know what could make py2exe not making proper .exe I would be glad to be helped.

Thank you.

Comment: try using `.iconphoto()`: https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-set-window-icon-in-tkinter/#root-iconphoto-to-set-window-icon also py2exe is probably not failing really, you just haven't correctly followed instructions

Comment: Do I have to rewrite all the code? And make MainWindow->root 
because the methord requires me to root.mainloop()

Comment: no it doesn't, it is just a variable name, simply do `MainWindow.iconphoto(...)`

Comment: It is not working in the script it recognize no image with this method, not .ico and not .jpg.. 
`_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "favicon.ico"` 
I tried to re download the picture to maybe find that my files are corrupted but it is in the same state.
The iconbitmap worked fine but I can't get why py2exe can't use that anymore

Comment: maybe you need to add that image to the .exe files separately